# How valuable is a regression result with serially correlated residuals?

Tags: regression, time-series, autocorrelation, residuals, stationarity

I performed a linear regression with two time series variables. First, I checked stationarity of both time series via ADF/PP/KPSS tests and all three indicated non-stationarity. However the test of Zivot/Andrews (specified in R as ur.za) indicated that both series are (trend)-stationary. I concluded that both variables are suitable for a regression. As a result I got significant results (also the direction i expected) but, however, also serial correlation for the residuals.

[image: Serial Correlation of Residuals]

After differencing both the dependent and independent variables, the correlation of the residuals was removed but the relationship also not significant anymore.

[image: ACF of Residuals after differencing]

Now my question is, how good the results of the first model are or if i need to perform at a transformation as I did in the second step?

Comment: Just note that differencing is a suitable transformation only for a very special case: when the variables are integrated but not cointegrated. Since you have concluded (by doing the `ur.za` test) that the variables are not integrated, differencing might not be a good idea.

Comment: You have a third option, estimating a linear regression with a specified structure for the autocorrelation of the errors (AR(1) looks reasonable based on the plot): https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6469/simple-linear-model-with-autocorrelated-errors-in-r.

Comment: why don't you post the data and I will try and help

Comment: Many thanks for the responses. Richard, what would be the solution for the case if both are integrated AND cointegrated?